# Phoenix 1.4: How can I keep a DBConnection across multiple requests?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, connection-pooling, ecto

I have a Phoenix application with Elixir 1.9, Phoenix 1.4, with PostgreSQL database. This app serves as an API server.

It needs a feature like this:

Assuming that it runs 1000 concurrent processes that connect to the database with a DB pool size of 100. Each of the processes needs to run 5 different queries.

Normally in a setup like this, the 1000 processes will share 100 DBConnection in the pool, and take turn to run queries, each process will run 1 or 2 queries, or a few queries, and it gives the connection to the another process to run. The processes keep sharing the connections in the pool to run queries until all of them finish all 5 queries for each.

**Question:** Is there any config or directive to force each process to finish all 5 queries before it can give the connection back to the pool to share?

Comment: I don't understand why you want this, but anyway, wrapping the queries in a transaction should work.

Comment: Each process is a task that goes different ways with different sets of queries, each depends on the outcome of the previous one, so it is not convenient to wrap all of them in a transaction.

But it is an interesting idea. I will see if we can utilize it in certain way.

Answer (score 4):

> Normally in a setup like this, the 1000 processes will share 100 DBConnection in the pool [...]

It was “normally” before 2019 and [Broadway](https://hexdocs.pm/broadway). Actually even before 2016 and [GenStage](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage), but Broadway made handling backpressure a charm. Nowadays we usually put `GenStage` (low level) or `Broadway` (high level) backpressure handler between consumers and the potential bottleneck (DB in your case.) That is way more robust compared to a pool of workers.

> force each process to finish all 5 queries before it can give the connection back

Wrap your queries in [`Ecto.Multi`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html).

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at those things.